# What is the meaning of JK flip flop's J and K?

Tags: flipflop, terminology, history

In D flip flop, D means DATA. In SR flip flop, S means SET and R means RESET. What is the meaning of JK flip flop's J and K?

Comment: Only speculation, but quaternions use i, j, and k as unit vectors, such that i\*j\*k = -1. The flip-flop might be adopting this convention. Then it would be computing Q\*J\*K with Q=±1, J=1 or j, K=1 or k, the next state being Q=1 if the result is 1, k, or -k, else Q'=1 if -1, j, or -j. (Perhaps another formulation is more elegant.)

Comment: can we unprotect this so it can be closed as primarily opinion based?

Comment: A recent answer to a very similar question provided evidence that the correct answer is **not** opinion-based.

Comment: As pointed out in [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/149165/what-does-the-d-stand-for-in-d-flip-flop?noredirect=1&lq=1), the D in the D flip-flop was originally intended to stand for "delay."  (Phister, 1958)

Answer (score 22):

Here's what [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)) says: -

> According to P. L. Lindley, a JPL engineer, the flip-flop types
>   discussed below (RS, D, T, JK) were first discussed in a 1954 UCLA
>   course on computer design by Montgomery Phister, and then appeared in
>   his book Logical Design of Digital Computers. Lindley was at the time
>   working at Hughes Aircraft under Dr. Eldred Nelson, who had coined the
>   term JK for a flip-flop which changed states when both inputs were on.
>   The other names were coined by Phister. They differ slightly from some
>   of the definitions given below. Lindley explains that he heard the
>   story of the JK flip-flop from Dr. Eldred Nelson, who is responsible
>   for coining the term while working at Hughes Aircraft. Flip-flops in
>   use at Hughes at the time were all of the type that came to be known
>   as J-K. In designing a logical system, Dr. Nelson assigned letters to
>   flip-flop inputs as follows: #1: A & B, #2: C & D, #3: E & F, #4: G &
>   H, #5: J & K. Nelson used the notations "j-input" and "k-input" in a
>   patent application filed in 1953.

[Here](http://www.ideafinder.com/history/inventors/kilby.htm) is a link to a Jack Kilby biography that says he started at TI in 1958 and doesn't mention JK flip flops at all.

[This](http://www.ti.com/corp/docs/company/history/timeline/semicon/1950/docs/58ic_kilby.htm) TI website about Jack Kilby also doesn't mention JK flip flops either

If you look halfway down column 13 of this [patent](http://www.google.com/patents?id=JNUAAAAAEBAJ&pg=PA15#v=onepage&q&f=false) filed in 1953 (Granted 1958) you will see mention of inputs to a flip flop called J and K. This patent pre-dates Jack Kilby's time at TI by 5 years: -

[image]

Comment: And of course the letter I was probably skipped for the same reason that we use \$j = \sqrt{-1}\$ in electronics. :)

Comment: @Kaz - don't mention that to the mathematics guys

Comment: @Kaz: I don't think so: as much as I know often the letter i is skipped when letters are used for numbering (actually "lettering") because i and j or I and 1 look so similar and may get confused. It is rather an *optional* convention. In electronics it seems to be another problem (often it's no problem when  several very similar letters are used at the same time: e.g. \$\nu\$ and v or \$\omega\$ and w etc.). The problem in electronics is that _exactly_ the same letter i normally used for imaginary unit is also used for current. So one *must* yield  necessarily.

Comment: So it's been long since I was in school, but as soon as I read the question, my memory told me: "Jordan & Kelly". So I've tried searching for it, and [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_%28electronics%29) tells me: "The first electronic flip-flop was invented in 1918 by [...] William Eccles and F. W. Jordan." So the 'Jordan' could be right (tribute to him?). Maybe my 'Kelly' should be 'Kilby' but that's not what I recall, and it's pretty clear by now that he had nothing to do with it. Anyone ever heard of this 'Jordan & Kelly(?)' explanation? Or is my memory failing me?