# What does the T stand for in "T flip-flop"?

Tags: flipflop, terminology, history

The meaning of the letters J and K in "JK flip-flop" was previously discussed [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/79884/8090), and the meaning of the letter D in "D flip-flop" was previously discussed [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/149165/8090).

What does the T stand for in "T flip-flop"?

Answer (score 4):

Some people believe that the "T" in "T flip-flop" stands for "toggle," but I believe that it originally was intended to stand for "trigger."

According to the Wikipedia entry on [flip-flops](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Flip-flop_(electronics)&oldid=949243644),

> According to P. L. Lindley, an engineer at the US Jet Propulsion Laboratory, the flip-flop types detailed below (SR, D, T, JK) were first discussed in a 1954 UCLA course on computer design by Montgomery Phister, and then appeared in his book Logical Design of Digital Computers.[10][11] Lindley was at the time working at Hughes Aircraft under Eldred Nelson, who had coined the term JK for a flip-flop which changed states when both inputs were on (a logical "one"). The other names were coined by Phister.

In Montgomery Phister Jr.'s book *Logical Design of Digital Computers* (New York: John Wiley & Sons, Inc., 1958, pp. 126-127), he states

> **The *T* Flip-flop**
>
> The *T* or *trigger* memory element has a single input line which causes the memory element to change state when it is "one," but leaves it in its former state otherwise.

Because it seems that Phister was the first one to use the term "T flip-flop" and he used the "T" to stand for "trigger," it seems that this is what it was originally intended to mean.